# Where to call resource for this backup-cookbook

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

I am trying to use [backup-cookbook](https://github.com/gofullstack/backup-cookbook), and it's my first time trying to use the resource.

However when I try to call the resource "backup_model" it complains "Cannot find a resource for backup_model". So I know I must have put it in the wrong place.

I use librarian-chef. I am using chef-solo on a local Vagrant server.

site-cookbooks/c/recipes/default.rb

```
backup_model :ct_backup do
  ...
end
```

roles/backup.rb

```
name "backup"
description "Backup role."
run_list(
  "role[base]",
  "recipe[backup-cookbook]"
)
```

node.json

```
{
  "run_list":[
    "role[base]",
    "role[backup]",
    "recipe[c]"
  ]
}
```

When I try to run `knife solo cook` I got the following errors:

```
NameError
---------
Cannot find a resource for backup_model on ubuntu version 12.04


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /home/chefy/chef-solo/cookbooks-2/ct/recipes/default.rb:33:in `from_file'
```

Comment: Does cp have `depends 'backup'` in the metadata.rb?

Comment: @sethvargo I have put depends 'backup-cookbook' in. If I put 'backup' it will complain.

Comment: Thanks. Have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made the stupid mistake that in the Cheffile I used

```
cookbook 'backup-cookbook', git: 'git@github.com:gofullstack/backup-cookbook.git'
```

But the correct name should be:

```
cookbook 'backup',  git: 'git@github.com:gofullstack/backup-cookbook.git'
```